# Web Cam server using motion daemon video not crisp

Tags: webcam, streaming-video, motion

I have interfaced a web cam with rasberry pi and stream live video using motion daemon. I want the frame rate to increase and the video to be crisp. Is there any possible solution?

Comment: Are you using any of the motion-detecting-features of `motion` ?

Comment: What is the framerate you have right now? And what do you want?

Comment: Whats not *crisp* on your current images?

Comment: Where are you streaming to? diskrecorder? website? vlc? locally or worldwideweb?

Comment: Please be more clear in your question

Comment: @ExploWare I used tutorial http://techspect.co.uk/2013/how-to-raspberry-pi-webcam-server-stream/

Comment: The video that streams is not continuous. In the config option the frame rate is 2 I have tried changing it but no difference.

Comment: `Motion` is not made for streaming, although it can. It's overhead is to big if you don't need the other options from this wonderful piece of software. Try finding a good tutorial on streaming for Raspberry Pi that doesn't use Motion, that way there will be more capacity for more frames

Comment: AND this tutorial is even using X, which also take a lot of power away from the Pi

Answer (score 1):

This tutorial has served me well in the past: http://wolfpaulus.com/jounal/embedded/raspberrypi_webcam

It uses mjpegstreamer instead of motion. It should fit your needs way better than motion